# How to create light weight, fast and a clean web page

Tags: html

I frequently need to pop up the form html tags in `lightbox` so where should i store these form tags?

**1.** should i store tags in server and get via ajax fn() `: web page looks very clean`

**2.** or should i just write somewhere in webpage and get innerHTML tags by `js fn()` `: web page looks lengthy`.

Whether i am not very clear about the light weight & fast loading. Does it really matter if i choose to write the tags in webpage, what do you say ??

Answer (score 2):

If I understood well, you have several forms which you want to display in a lightbox (jQuery?). If that's correct, I think it will be lighter to add a few lines to your code than making a query for retrieve them.

Think about having your forms at the end of your file (or in a separate file containing all the forms you want to display that you include in the main page). You could select them by using css selectors like

```
$('.form1').lightbox()
```

Sorry if this is not the answer you look for but I can't comment on the post.

Answer (score 1):

Rules of optimization:

1. don't optimize
2. don't optimize (yet)

More specifically, I would say to go with the simplest method (inner html) then change it later if you identify a performance problem. HTML pages can be quite lengthy these days, check a twitter page for example, you'd be surprised...